# Why does WordData fail to find "PartsOfSpeech" when given a list of two words?

Tags: curated-data, linguistics

I have the following sample code.

```
StringSplit["a test string", " "]
Thread[WordData[%, "PartsOfSpeech"]]
```

The output I get is:

```
{a, test, string}
{{Noun, Preposition, Determiner}, {Noun, Verb}, {Noun, Verb}}
```

If I change `"a test string"` to `"test string"`, then my code fails, giving the following:

```
{test, string}
{}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Map`, not `Thread`.

```
data = StringSplit["a test string"];
WordData[#, "PartsOfSpeech"] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{"Noun", "Preposition", "Determiner"}, {"Noun", "Verb"}, {"Noun", "Verb"}}
> ```

```
WordData[#, "PartsOfSpeech"] & /@ Rest @ data
```

> ```
> {{"Noun", "Verb"}, {"Noun", "Verb"}}
> ```

The reason `Thread` doesn't work for `{"test", "string"}` is that `WordData` interprets a 1st argument that is a two element list as the form `{<word>, <part-of-speech>}` and returns `{ }`, because "string" is not a part-of-speech. For a three-element or longer list it returns unevaluated, in which case, `Thread` can operate on it.

#### Edit

Pickett points out `WordData` will evaluate for some 1st arguments consisting of three element lists, but what is returned is still not an appropriate argument for `Thread`. For `Thread` to be applicable to this problem, the `WordData` expression given to it must be returned unevaluated. Therefore,  I assert that it is not a good idea to use `Thread` for what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: `WordData[{"test", "Noun", "Run"}]` evaluates. The third parameter is the "sense" of the word, so I don't understand why it evaluates for a list of three elements but not for two.

Comment: @Pickett  I think the third element has to be a valid sense tag, or `WordData[..., "PartsOfSpeech"]` returns unevaluated.  Try `WordData[{"test", "Noun", "run"}, "PartsOfSpeech"]`.  It is because `WordData[{"a", "test", "string"}, "PartsOfSpeech"]` returns unevaluated that `Thread` happens to work for the OP.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah yes, I see now that that's how it works when you have `PartsOfSpeech` as the second argument. Without that it evaluates even with an invalid sense. Thanks for clarifying. +1 for this answer.